# How can I load webform content inside a custom webform composite element?

Tags: 8, webforms

I am using Drupal 8.7.3 and Webform 8.x-5.2.

I created a custom composite field in a multistep webform by extending WebformCompositeBase. My users select a subject in an earlier step. In this step I want to take the key of the user selection and request data based on this key.

```
class OtherExpectationsComposite extends WebformCompositeBase {
    public static function getCompositeElements(array $element) {
        return [
            'depending_content' => [
                '#markup' => 'content depending on earlier selections'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

How can I load the data insert to the form by the user in the earlier steps? `$element` doesn't contain anything helpful.

Comment: The currently available APIs don't support this level of conditional logic.

Comment: Ohh what a pitty. That's why I can't find a nice solution. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the good old session.

My solution:

```
//mymodule.module
function mymodule_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
    $session->set('value_from_earlier_step', $form_state->get('value_from_earlier_step'));
}

//\src\Element\ExampleComposite.php
class ExampleComposite extends WebformCompositeBase {
    public static function getCompositeElements(array $element) {
        $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
        $expectations = $session->get('value_from_earlier_step');
    }
}
```